# make: Nothing to be done for `all'. when i tried to compile

Tags: linux, module, makefile, kernel

this is the code of my make file

```
obj-m +=hello-1.o
all:
<tab>make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
<tab>make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

AND I HAVE FEW QUESTIONS

1. we save  C language file with extension *.c so for Makefile which extension should we use?
2. When i throw command in terminal "make" it gives me error that 
   make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

Comment: The `Makefile` itself doesn't have an extension just `Makefile`.

Comment: Is your source file `hello-1.c`? What does `make -rRd` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the file `all` already exists.  As it doesn't depend on anything, and isn't a dependency of `.PHONY`, its existence is sufficient to consider it made.

I would suggest adding

```
.PHONY: all clean
```

to the end of `Makefile`.

You are allowed to call the file anything you like, as long as that is `Makefile` ;-)  Actually, there's a couple of non-standard names that may be used as fallbacks, or you can provide a name with the `-f` flag to `make`, but I wouldn't recommend either of those if you're in a position to avoid them.

Other comments (for which you didn't ask, but you're getting anyway):

1. Avoid invoking `make` literally in a command; always use `$(MAKE)`.  This helps when you use `-n`, for instance.
2. Don't prevent your makefile's users from building for a kernel other than that which is running now.  Create a variable for it (e.g. `KVER := $(shell uname -r)` or `KSRC := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build` so it can be overridden on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir but i want to know something that 
I'm learning from this source http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x181.html
when i copy code and paste it and it works fully. But if i just remove that 'tab' which is below "all: " and before "make" .
after removing that i try to put ' tab ' it won't work at all.
so i want to know is there any rules for writing make files like this? and what should i do to run it manually putting tab over that.